# Using virtual in C#

Tags: c#, oop, virtual

What is the purpose of `virtual` in C#? What is the proper way and reason to use it?

For example, `public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }` in defining a collection orders in a `Client` class (say, at a restaurant or something). Why would you use virtual here? What does it do, and what is the general correct way to use it?

Comment: Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: It is one of the three pillars on which Object Oriented Programming rests.  Too large a subject to handle in an SO answer, it is well covered in many books you'll find in your local bookstore or library.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has the answer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that inherits it:

If you were to create a child class that inherits from the Client, you would be able to override this method and make it read only, or modify the get clause, limit the size of the collection added.....etc

Answer (score 1):

Defining a property/method/etc of a class as virtual gives you the ability to override it in a derived class.

Why you would use it with a 'client class say at a restaurant or something' depends on how you differentiate between different clients. If one subgroup of clients always orders the same thing, you could for example override the Orders property in their derived class (from client) to always return that particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions are not specific to C#. They allow algorithms, implemented to operate on objects of certain base class `Parent`, to continue functioning on objects of class `Child`, derived from class `Parent`, without knowing `Child`'s implementation details.

A simple example: [Object.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx). We may have a form with various controls. If we want to check what controls we have, we could do:

```
foreach (control in form.Controls)
  Debug.Print(control.ToString())
```

Each control belongs to a certain class which always has `Object` class in its ancestry tree, and can override `ToString` to provide its own meaningful implementation of it. However, we don't need to know the implementation details of `ToString` of each control class we use on the form, to make this work. We don't even need to know if `ToString` has been overridden or not.

Sometimes, designers of class libraries deliberately mark a class method as virtual, even though the default method implementation is expected to be quite generic at the first glance. That's done for future flexibility. This might be the case with your `public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }` example. A developer who may be deriving a new class from the `Client` class in the future will have an option to provide an alternative behavior for `Orders` property. The code in the base library which, for example, is responsible for processing orders, will continue to work correctly with such new classes, on the binary level. There will be no need to recompile the base library.